# Definite article: (the) wetlands throughout Florida have been drained

Tags: definite-article

Is there a difference with or without the in this case? I feel there is no difference in meaning.

Below is the context, if needed.

> This could be because global warming has contributed to an increase in
> overall temperatures in the region or because wetlands throughout
> Florida have been drained.

Feel free to provide more contexts that could illustrate their difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including the article in OP's context more strongly implies ***all** [of the] wetlands* were drained. Without it, we might well suppose the optional but unspecified "determiner" here could have been, for example, ***some***.

Most likely ***all*** of the wetlands *haven't* been drained, so it's probably better not to include it.